# How to take backup of installed applications (.apk) to sdcard?

Tags: android

I like to take all 3rd party application's backup to the SD Card. I tried out to copy .apk file from /data folder but no such permission to do so.
Please let me know is there any way to grant permissions or another way to take application backup.

Thanks

Comment: Unless your phone is rooted, you won't be able to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but so many aaps are available in the market that takes app backup on non rooted phone :)

Comment: Who cares if you found the solution if you are not going to share it?

Comment: If you found the solution please post your answer and close this.